# Python user input formatting

Tags: python, formatting

When manipulating user input like - 12345 - to add dashes inbetween chars like - 1-2-3-4-5,  I know that we can run something like:

```
print(uInp, end=' -')
```

However, the output becomes: 1-2-3-4-5-

With the dash on the end failing the outcome.

How do I get rid of the dash at the end when using end='-'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
>>> s = '12345'
>>> '-'.join(s)
'1-2-3-4-5'
>>> help(str.join)
Help on method_descriptor:

join(self, iterable, /)
    Concatenate any number of strings.
    
    The string whose method is called is inserted in between each given string.
    The result is returned as a new string.
    
    Example: '.'.join(['ab', 'pq', 'rs']) -> 'ab.pq.rs'
```

Comment: Documentation is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join